# Python Pandas rolling sum operation for subset of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-sum

This is best explained through an example.

I have the following dataframe (each row can be thought of as a transaction):

```
DATE        AMOUNT
2017-01-29  10 
2017-01-30  20
2017-01-31  30
2017-02-01  40
2017-02-02  50
2017-02-03  60
```

I would like to compute a 2-day rolling sum but only for rows in February.

Code snippet I have currently:

`df.set_index('DATE',inplace=True)`

`res=df.rolling('2d')['AMOUNT'].sum()`

which gives:

```
            AMOUNT 
2017-01-29  10 
2017-01-30  30 
2017-01-31  50 
2017-02-01  70 
2017-02-02  90 
2017-02-03  110
```

but I really only need the output in the last 3 rows, the operations on the first 3 rows are unnecessary. When the dataframe is huge, this incurs immense time complexity. How do I compute the rolling sum only for the last 3 rows (other than computing the rolling sum for all rows and then doing a row filtering operation after that)?

*I cannot pre-filter the dataframe either because there wouldn't be the 'lookback' period in January for the correct rolling sum value to be obtained.

Comment: What is expected output? There are data with multiple years?

Comment: @jezrael I'm dealing with a dataset of a few million transactions over 2 years but I only require rolling sum values computed for the second year. The rolling window is 1 year. Thus when I apply the rolling function to all rows, there's 'wasted' computation for a year worth of transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use timedelta to filter your df and keep the last day of January.

```
import datetime  

dateStart = datetime.date(2017, 2, 1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
dateEnd = datetime.date(2017, 2, 3)
df.loc[dateStart:dateEnd]
```

Then you can do your rolling operation and drop the first line (which is 2017-01-31)

Comment: I did consider this, but the problem is that when my rolling window increases to say 1 year, I'd have to keep an extra year of transactions. Ideally I want to compute the rolling sum _only_ for the February transactions.

Comment: An other way is to create a column with the value of days -1 : df['AMOUT1'] = df.Amout.shift(1) and then filter the df and do df.AMOUT = df.AMOUT + df.AMOUT1

Comment: df['AMOUNT1'] = df.AMOUNT.shift(1) assumes the rolling window is a fixed number of rows. Not sure how the shifting should be implemented with a time-based window (unless I resample the dataframe such that every row corresponds to 1 day). Does get me what I want but the additional operations could be more time eating than saving.

Answer (score 0):

you can just compute the rolling sum only for the last rows by using `tail(4)`

```
res = df.tail(4).rolling('2d')['AMOUNT'].sum()
```

Output:

```
DATE
2017-01-31      NaN
2017-02-01     70.0
2017-02-02     90.0
2017-02-03    110.0
Name: AMOUNT, dtype: float64
```

If you want to merge those values - excluding 2017-01-31 then you can do the following:

```
df.loc[res.index[1:]] = res.tail(3)
```

Output:

```
            AMOUNT
DATE    
2017-01-29  10.0
2017-01-30  20.0
2017-01-31  30.0
2017-02-01  70.0
2017-02-02  90.0
2017-02-03  110.0
```

Comment: That gives me 40 for the 2017-02-01 row, which is incorrect (should be 70).

Comment: Hmm ok you're right.. but I think you just needed to do tail(4)? But I'm on my phone now so I didn't test it.

Comment: @ZiXiang doing `tail(4)` does give the data you wanted. I have also edited the answer to show you how to add `res` to the main df if this is desired.